# Fbconsole output error

Tags: python, facebook, oauth

I use [fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole) for authetication on Facebook.

```
import fbconsole
fbconsole.APP_ID = '1234567890'
fbconsole.AUTH_SCOPE = ['publish_stream', 'publish_checkins', 'read_stream',         'offline_access']
fbconsole.authenticate()
newsfeed = fbconsole.get('/me/home', {'fields':'from,name,description,message'})
newsfeedData = newsfeed["data"]
for status in newsfeedData:
    print status['from']['name'];
    print status['created_time'];
    #print status['name']
    print status['message']
    #print status.encode("utf-8")
    print('##############################################################################')
```

The `status['from']['name']` shows name of friend, but `status['message']` shows KeyError. How can I print news from Facebook, if `'status'` is dictionary type and it HAS the `'message'` key??? The same error is printing on `'name'` key.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there are no "**name**" and "**message**" values and in such cases facebook doesn't include them in the response. This might be the reason it throws errors. I guess you should check if key exists. But honestly I have no idea how to do it in Python.

Comment: You can "get" keys to avoid KeyError, e.g.: `d = {'foo': 'bar'}; a = d.get('baz', 'qux'); a == 'qux'`. Basically you can either provide a default value (here `'qux'`) or when the key isn't found `None` will be returned instead. See the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (try, except) block of python to resolve the issue.
for e.g.

```
try:
 print(status['message'])
except(KeyError):
 print("This post doesn't contain any message")
 continue
```